# How can I edit mongo db config using bash?

Tags: mongodb, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that checks the state of the nodes included in the mongo db configuration and, in case one of them is unavailable, assigns him zero vote and priority.

The problem is that I can't use any extra packages for bash. How can I create a new configuration for rs.reconfig() on the fly using bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGOSHELL=$mongo_dir' --host '$host' --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u ' $user' -p '$psw

$MOGOSHELL 'rs.conf()' // object type
res=`$MONGOSHELL 'rs.config()'` // string type
```

I think it's possible to parse the string somehow, but I'm not sure if this is a good solution.

Tell me how best to solve the problem of editing the configuration without using additional bash add-ons?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
$MONGOSHELL "ctf=rs.conf();cnf.members[$n].priority=2;cnf.members[$n].votes=1;rs.reconfig(cnf,{force:true})"
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31812305)

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA The OP indicates this solved their problem. As such it is an answer (though not a great answer), and not something that should be an edit to their question.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.